# How to append value to all subarrays in PHP without a loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        'id' => ...
        'name' ...
   ),
   [1] => Array (
        'id' => ...
        'name' ...
   ),
   [2] => Array (
        'id' => ...
        'name' ...
   ),
   [3] => Array (
        'id' => ...
        'name' ...
   ),
)
```

What I want to do is to append the same `pid` key-value pair to every subarray. Is there an easy way to do this without having to do a `foreach`?

Comment: Short answer: no; Just loop through the array and append it to each subArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without having to explicitly use a `foreach` or some other kind of loop, you can use PHP's [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function. although this will perform an iterated loop under the hood, it will return an array with each element processed by your function.

```
<?php
$arr = Array (
   0 => Array (
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'one'
   ),
   1 => Array (
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'two'
   ),
   2 => Array (
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'three'
   ),
   3 => Array (
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'four'
   )
);

function append_pid_kvpair($n){
  $n ['pid']= 'value';
  return $n;
}

$arr = array_map("append_pid_kvpair",$arr);

echo "<pre>".print_r($arr,true)."</pre>";
```

will result in this output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => one
            [pid] => value
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => two
            [pid] => value
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => three
            [pid] => value
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => four
            [pid] => value
        )

)
```