# PHP - Add a default value to all the subarrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array that has some sub arrays. I need to add a default value to all of the sub arrays. I've tried some suggestions but none of the helped.

```
array(1) { ["ClassOne"]=> 
                { 
                [0]=>{ ["rollno"]=> "C1" ["dateofbirth"]=> "1974-06-07"} 
                [1]=>{ ["rollno"]=> "C2" ["dateofbirth"]=> "1970-01-01"} 
                }

            }
```

needs to changed to

```
array(1) { ["ClassOne"]=> 
                { 
                [0]=> { ["rollno"]=> "C1" ["dateofbirth"]=> "1974-06-07" ["defaultValue"]=> "someValue"} 
                [1]=> { ["rollno"]=> "C2" ["dateofbirth"]=> "1970-01-01" ["defaultValue"]=> "someValue"} 
                }

            }
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried(code), and we'll help you on your way

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984287/how-to-append-value-to-all-subarrays-in-php-without-a-loop

Comment: Are you generating this array or is it coming from some external source?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append value to all subarrays in PHP without a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984287/how-to-append-value-to-all-subarrays-in-php-without-a-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach to get the index where you are going to append the "defaultvalue" Hope this answer is sufficient,thanks

```
/* your array as describred */

$array = array(
    array("ClassOne"=>
    array( "rollno"=> "C1","dateofbirth"=> "1974-06-07" ),
    array( "rollno"=> "C2","dateofbirth"=> "1970-01-01"),
    ),
    array("ClassTwo"=>
    array( "rollno"=> "C1","dateofbirth"=> "1974-06-07" ),
    array( "rollno"=> "C2","dateofbirth"=> "1970-01-01"),
    )

);

 foreach($array as $key=>$value)
  {
    foreach($array[$key] as $key1 => $value1)
    $array[$key][$key1]['defaultValue']='someValue';

  }

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just map a function and add the new array:

```
$a = ["defaultValue" => "someValue"];
$array = array_map(function($v) use($a) { return $v + $a; }, $array);
```

Or walk it:

```
array_walk($array, function(&$v, $k, $a) { $v = $v + $a; }, ["defaultValue" => "someValue"]);
```